# Import csv and output directory, name and owner of each file. showing invalid argument

Tags: powershell, loops, variables, foreach

I used a tool to find corrupted PDFs in a directory, and outputted the path to those PDFs to a csv. I am trying to take the contents of that CSV and get the directory, filename and owner of those files. My script is throwing an error that seems to indicate there is an issue with values in my CSV.  If I do it manually (without the loop) I get the expected results.  I just started writing my own scripts (trying not to be a script kiddie anymore), and look forward to learning from any help/guidance provided.

Thanks in advance!
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

My Script:

```
$FileList = import-csv "C:\scripts\CorruptedPDFinder_results.csv"
foreach ($File in $FileList){
write-verbose "Reading $File..." -verbose
get-item $File | select directory,name,@{name="Owner";expression = {(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}}
}
```

Output:

```
VERBOSE: Reading @{FilePath=    \\vs30\Sales_Jackets\COMPANY_83\Sales Orders\18393\Invoice #18393 - Print_072718140428.pdf  }...
get-item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:4 char:1
+ get-item $File | select directory,name,@{name="Owner";expression = {( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\scripts\@{Fi...718140428.pdf }:String) [Get-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

get-item : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\@{FilePath= \vs30\Sales_Jackets\COMPANY_83\Sales Orders\18393\Invoice #18393 - Print_072718140428.pdf   }' because it does not exist.
At line:4 char:1
+ get-item $File | select directory,name,@{name="Owner";expression = {( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\scripts\@{Fi...718140428.pdf  }:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

If I do it manually (without the loop) I get the expected results.  I just started writing my own scripts (trying not to be a script kiddie anymore), and look forward to learning from any help/guidance provided.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CSV contains a header, so probably if your csv is like below.

```
FilePath    Column2    Column3
--------    ---------  ---------
path1      somevalue1  somevalue2
```

Then here is how you select path in the iteration. You have to cherry pick the property.

```
Foreach($File in $FileList){
    Get-Item -Path $File.FilePath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the correct member.  When you use `Import-Csv`, you're getting a `pscustomobject` array that represents each row with the properties matching the headers.

If you're on v3+ (implements automatic member enumeration):

```
foreach ($file in $FileList.FilePath) {
    Get-Item -Path $file
}
```

v2:

```
foreach ($file in ($FileList | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FilePath)) {
```

---

If you care about the other headers, the other answer is probably more suitable as you can work with them while in the loop block.

Comment: I am on 5.1 and the file locations are on a server running 5.1.  I've updated my script to reflect your first example.  The error that I see now is referring to get-item can't find the path.  The interesting thing in the error occurs after it reads the first object in the CSV then craps out.

`get-item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:4 char:1
+ get-item -Path $File | select directory,name,@{name="Owner";expressio ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\scripts\ \vs...2218092900.pdf :String) [Get-Item], ArgumentException`

Comment: @RyanB Do you have illegal characters in the path?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  An example of the content of the CSV is: \\vs30\Sales_Jackets\COMPANY_83\Sales Orders\13492\Invoice #13492 - Print_062918084314.pdf